# Can I use a field on my test class as a parameter to an XUnit Theory?

Tags: xunit

I like to define named test data as fields on my test class, and sometimes multiple are run against the same test using a Theory.
I've used `MemberData` but this appears to only support `IEnumerable` so I have to write somewhat ugly wrapper enumerables:

```
public class MyTests
{
    public static string s1 = "test";
    public static string s2 = "bees";
    public static string s3 = "pear";
    public static string s4 = "joke";

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> Strings => new List<object[]>
    {
        new object[] { s1 },
        new object[] { s2 },
        new object[] { s3 },
        new object[] { s4 },
    };

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(Strings))]
    public void ContainsLetterE(string s)
    {
        s.Should().Contain("e");
    }
}
```

What I am wondering is if there is a way to use explicit fields/properties, along the lines of:

```
public class MyTests
{
    public static string s1 = "test";
    public static string s2 = "bees";
    public static string s3 = "pear";
    public static string s4 = "joke";

    [Theory]
    [Field(nameof(s1))]
    [Field(nameof(s2))]
    [Field(nameof(s3))]
    [Field(nameof(s4))]
    public void ContainsLetterE(string s)
    {
        s.Should().Contain("e");
    }
}
```

Is this possible at all, or does it have to be `IEnumerable` based?

Comment: will something like this work for you? : `[Theory] public void ContainsLetterE([TestValues("a", "b", "c")]string s)` ? Which effectively will call your test 3 times with different values in `s`

Comment: also what about InlineDataAttribute https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/?

Comment: if you need passing particular class values, you can define these values as constant and then pass his value itself into for example InlineDataAttribute

Comment: The point is I want the test case data explicitly listed like in my example as these are used in multiple tests, or may be more complex than simple strings, for readbility.`InlineDataAttribute` means I have to re-type the same in several places which increases risk of error. It seems exposing an enumerable property wrapping them is the only solution, although a deleted answer suggests passing the names of the properties as inline data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it as answer since it's quite big.

> InlineDataAttribute means I have to re-type the same in several places which increases risk of error.

if you define this as constants then you can provide these constants itself instead of typing values.

if you don't want doing it, then you have a huge number of xunit customization approaches that will require some work though.

1. You can define your own attribute inherited from `DataAttribute` (See example [here](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-custom-xunit-theory-test-dataattribute-to-load-data-from-json-files/)).

   ```
   public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
   ...
   ```

Then if you add this attribute to your test, in `MethodInfo testMethod` you will have full information about test itself, base class and so on, including applied custom attributes. One workflow example that you can consider is using this new data attribute (for a test itself) with a different custom attribute like `ValuesAttribute` similar to:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public sealed class ValuesAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly object[] _values;

    public ValuesAttribute(params object[] values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }

    public object[] GenerateValues()
    {
        return _values;
    }
}
```

which will allow you reading custom input for a test and generate test cases in flight. If I understand what you're asking correctly it will be:

```
[Theory]
[CustomDataAttribute]
public void Test(Values(nameof(s1), nameof(s2)) OutputType value)
...
```

where inside `CustomDataAttribute` you will need to read ValuesAttribute value from parameter via reflection, then read fields you need from the test class itself with reflection too and eventually properly fill output here `public override IEnumerable<object[]>` as OutputType.

2. Implement your own logic for MemberData like below. Note: it's simplified above approach since MemberDataAttributeBase is inherited from `DataAttribute`

   ```
   public class CustomMemberData : MemberDataAttributeBase
   {
      public CustomMemberData(string memberName, object[] parameters) : base(memberName, parameters)
      {
      }

      protected override object[] ConvertDataItem(MethodInfo testMethod, object item) => /*your logic*/;
   }
   ```

There are more ways, but the idea is that you can customize almost everything in xunit workflow if you need to :)  But you need to write some infrustructure for it.